# Laravel returning Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage\' not found in directory for any Storage function

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently trying to fetch a JSON file from a website, but now I've reduced it to any `Storage` functions in Laravel. Any code, such as this:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
Storage::disk('local')->put('test.txt', 'content');
```

just returns

```php
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage' not found in directory
```

So far, I've tried
`\Storage::disk('local')->put('test.txt', 'content);` without `use`, importing `use Storage;` or using other methods from `Storage`. None of them work, and I've even tried switching computers and installing a fresh `Laravel` package. All of them return the same error.

It's not the `text.txt`'s error, any legitimate file I put in don't work either.

I did check the alias for the keys, it does have the `Storage` alias under the alias array. I've also ran a skew of commands, such as `cache:clear` and `composer dump`, but to no avail.

Currently, I have this file in a custom directory in `app/Commons/web/script.php`, since it's a script I plan on running periodically.

Comment: Where are you putting that code? in a controller method? Could you show us something else?

Comment: Did you do composer install on your laravel? Did you check your config/filesystems.php

Comment: Try a `composer dump`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ It's in a custom directory in app, I edited my question.

Comment: Maybe you just need to require `vendor/autoload.php`? Autoload is magic, but you still need to cast the spell.

Comment: I think you should use it in a class function. I don't know what you have in that file, but in a flat php file it won't work

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ It's already in a class, I didn't want to complicate it further. Script style doesn't work either.

Comment: @Arcesilas How do I require autoload? If I do `require vendor\autoload.php`, just gives me No such file or directory error.

Comment: The vendor directory is relative to your project root so add ../../ up to yout root

Comment: However i would consider writing a console command in laravel and add it to the schedular. Plain script does not boot the framework

Comment: @DannyEbbers Looks like that was the problem, made a command, and used `Storage` there with no problems.

Comment: i bet that it's because the put function is not getting a well formatted file (mostly if you are passing a string)... please post the whole code where this line is used